# Blender export animation keyframes FBX to unity

Tags: export, keyframes, unity, .fbx, actions

I encounter an issues, when I want to export a FBX from blender to Unity. The problem is that in Unity are a lot of animations objects imported. [image]

[image]

And here are my blender settings, also I have uploded the blender file, here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/12SKtva3NYUQ9JWUdwg687FTe_-bi92Cj/view?usp=drive_link

I have tried any kind of blender fbx export settings, but nothing work...

Comment: Your link requires an account. You can use https://blend-exchange.com/ instead.